# I tried to use the mutex. Why did it automatically stop without an error

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I tried to use the mutex. Why did it automatically stop without an error.

Running will stop automatically after a while

This is my code, which can be run directly. Please help me to see what the problem is

Is my method wrong? Is there a better way to achieve it? I don't want my interface to get stuck

`

```
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QWaitCondition, QMutex
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QApplication, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 23))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "stop"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.__init2__()

    def __init2__(self):

        self.search_running = False
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.search)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop_search)

    def stop_search(self):
        if self.search_running:
            reply = QMessageBox.information(self, 'notice', 'Do you want to stop searching？',
                                            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel)
            if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.search_thread.terminate()
                self.__thread.resume()
                self.search_running = False
                self.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

        else:
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'tip', 'no search！', QMessageBox.Ok)

    def search(self):
        if not self.search_running:
            self.search_running = True
            self.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.search_thread = Search_Thread()
            self.search_thread.trigger.connect(lambda i: self.c(i))
            self.search_thread.complete.connect(self.search_complete)
            self.search_thread.start()

    def c(self, i):
        self.ui.label.setText(str(i))
        self.search_thread.resume()

    def search_complete(self):
        self.__thread.resume()
        self.search_running = False
        self.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(True)


class Search_Thread(QThread):
    trigger = pyqtSignal(int)
    complete = pyqtSignal()
    mutex = QMutex()
    cond = QWaitCondition()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.mutex.lock()
        for i in range(10000):
            for j in range(10000):
                print(j)
                for k in range(10000):
                    # time.sleep(0.1)
                    self.trigger.emit(i + j + k)
                    # time.sleep(0.1)
                    self.cond.wait(self.mutex)
        self.complete.emit()
        self.mutex.unlock()

    def resume(self):
        self.cond.wakeAll()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    height = 100
    width = 300
    window.setGeometry(int((screen.width() - width) / 2), int((screen.height() - height) / 2), width, height)
    window.setWindowTitle("test")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

`

help me,How to improve the code so that it does not stop automatically

Comment: As the documentation [explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html): "Releases the lockedMutex and waits on the wait condition. The lockedMutex must be initially locked by the calling thread. If lockedMutex is not in a locked state, the behavior is undefined.". Since `wait` unlocks the mutex, the next cycle of the loop it will get an unlocked state, which has unexpected behavior. You should probably use [`tryLock()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html#tryLock), but your code is a bit too abstract to understand what it should do and if that's what you actually need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still can't solve the problem after trying tryLock. Can you take a look at my previous problem? I am trying to make some time-consuming operations executed in a thread so that a control cannot be stuck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74224351/how-to-let-pyqt-update-the-ui-in-the-thread-without-blocking-the-interface